# What’s an authoritative source for a complete list of official shinjitai kanji?

Tags: kanji, kyūjitai-and-shinjitai

I found quite a few website tables and software conversors, but none that was both complete and authoritative.  Is there any place I can find such a list in digital format?

拡張新字体 would be a nice bonus, but what I’m really interested is the official list.

Comment: Which kanji set are you talking about? You probably couldn't get a complete or authritative list because you did not specify the set.

Comment: as far as I know, only the jōyō have “official” shinjitai; analogous shinjitai for non-jōyō kanji are considered “unofficial”.  so the set I was thinking about was jōyō.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official list of [jōyō kanji](http://kokugo.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/joho/kijun/naikaku/kanji/joyokanjisakuin/) 常用漢字 contains simplification information (e.g. 悪（惡） means "悪, which is the shinjitai of 惡").

The list of [jinmeiyō kanji](http://www.moj.go.jp/content/000058122.pdf) (PDF) 人名用漢字 also contains some info about simplification, in the opposite format, because here the meaning is "you can use 惡, which is the kyūjitai of 悪, in names."

These are probably the closest to an *official* list as you are going to get, if by "official" you mean "formally codified by the government of Japan." There may be websites who have rearranged the information so that it is in the sort of 旧字体:新字体 list you are after, but if they're privately run sites then they're one step away from officialdom.

Comment: Thanks! I _knew_ there was a more logical place to look than Unihan.

I’ve extracted my own list from the PDF, it’s available at http://namakajiri.net/kanjigen/shinjitai.txt .